# Creating an IFRAME using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage hosted online and I would like it to be possible that I could insert an IFRAME onto another webpage using some JavaScript.

How would this be the best way possible, that I just add my webpage URL to the JavaScript and that it work on all browsers?

Thanks

Comment: Presumably both pages are yours? You want to insert YourSiteA into an iframe within YourSiteB?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function prepareFrame() {
        var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://google.com/");
        ifrm.style.width = "640px";
        ifrm.style.height = "480px";
        document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    }
</script>
```

also check [basics of the iFrame element](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/externalhtml.shtml)

Comment: I get document is not defined when I try and use this?

Comment: @Sparlarva: I guess you aren't in the HTML DOM context then.

Answer (score 6):

It is better to process HTML as a template than to build nodes via JavaScript (HTML is not XML after all.) You can keep your IFRAME's HTML syntax clean by using a template and then appending the template's contents into another DIV.

```
<div id="placeholder"></div>

<script id="iframeTemplate" type="text/html">
    <iframe src="...">
        <!-- replace this line with alternate content -->
    </iframe>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var element,
    html,
    template;

element = document.getElementById("placeholder");
template = document.getElementById("iframeTemplate");
html = template.innerHTML;

element.innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

Comment: I haven't seen a `script[type=text/html]` before; is there any difference doing this as opposed to a `div[style=display:none]` ?

Comment: @David Cook the syntax you mentioned are for different purposes entirely. :)

Comment: Can you please give a full working example as I do not get the idea of template here. I would do it as in the top answer. Why is template better than js generated html? Never read of `script[type=text/html] ` as @DavidCook

Answer (score 0):

so I tried to put an embed youtube video to my index.html using google console API key, and this is the function that I made:

```
const searchVideos = async (key, search, maxResVideos) => {
    const config = { params: { key: key, q: search } }
    let res = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&maxResVideos=${maxResVideos}`, config);
    console.log('res:', res.data.items);
    res.data.items.forEach(item => {

        const video = document.createElement('div');
        video.innerHTML = `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${item.id.videoId}" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>`;
        searchResult.appendChild(video);
    });
}
```

you can still make changes but this puts the embed video by creating a div and putting the iframe as string template literals ...

Comment: Why the downvote for the answer that seems to work. Does the function work, what is your experience? Using innerHTML here is probably not as good as using js like `let ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");ifrm.setAttribute("src",'https://www.youtube.com/embed/v123' );ifrm.style.width = "300px";ifrm.style.height = "300px";`

Comment: The [google yt api link](https://googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search) is dead.