# Convert a link into an iframe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

So let's say I have a link

```
<a href="http://URL"></a>
```

In place of this link, I want to instead show an IFRAME that contains the contents of the link. Example:

```
<iframe src="http://URL"></iframe>
```

The width of this iframe would be 100% and the height of the iframe would dynamically be calculated to equal the height of the resulting page (aka the http://URL).

How would I do this with a pure Javascript solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an IFRAME using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726455/creating-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Comment: So its not as easy as i first imagined, hence my answer delete. Question.  Do your `<a>` elements have `id` names? More importantly is there any text between the `<a href...>` and here `</a>`.  I don't understand how you would even be able to see those links on the page as written?  Without these answers I don't know how its possible to proceed.

Comment: Yeah, you can add class or id to the <a> elements and have any text in between the <a href=""> and <a>

Comment: @t.niese That doesn't solve my question. I'm trying to convert a link to an iframe, with Javascript adjusting the frame size.

Comment: [make iframe height dynamic based on content inside- JQUERY/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162933)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, but it works only within the same domain name. It is security restrictions

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href="http://example.org" class="frame">example.org</a>
    </div>
    <script>
        var links = document.getElementsByClassName('frame');
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
            frame.setAttribute('src', links[i].getAttribute('href'));
            frame.setAttribute('class', links[i].getAttribute('class'));
            frame.style.width = "100%";
            frame.onload = function() {
                frame.style.height = frame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
            };

            links[i].parentNode.replaceChild(frame, links[i]);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would I change it so there's no domain restriction?

Comment: You could embed javascript code on remote server (or change server response headers) if it is yours, but I suppose it's not the case?
Then try the following library, I didn't actually use it: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer