# How to write Iframe to HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to write a iframe  to html from javascript the below code dosent work can anyone explain why

```
 <html>
<body>

<script>
document.write("<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Ow8QgoXzeE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, you need `\"` inside the string. Write `document.write("<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Ow8QgoXzeE\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>");`

Comment: This has already been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726455/creating-an-iframe-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sublime to ensure you don't do such mistakes. It's mistake of " and ' :

either way it will work:

```
<script>
document.write('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Ow8QgoXzeE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
document.write("<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Ow8QgoXzeE' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
</script>
```

In your code, reason why it doesn't work is that you are using all way : **"** and that is why it will not be recognizable where your string ends and starts.

For more clarification, see this:

```
var ex = "its "important" to know";//wrong
var ex = "its 'important' to know";//right
var ex = 'its "important" to know';//right
```

You can see that first statement gets processed as one string: "its " and other string "to know" but not characters between(important).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work, find below the new code:

**Javascript:**

```
document.write("<iframe width='560' height='315' src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/9Ow8QgoXzeE' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
```

And here the working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/fzzkb1jx/

Hope it helps!