# Get contents from href="' & bring it into an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

`<a href="chat9867.php?user=Emma">Chat With Emma</a>`
It is a code to access profile chatting page in my site! Editing & removing this code is locked due to their security reasons.

But I want it to be inside of an `iframe`:- `<iframe src="chat9867.php?user=Emma" width="100%" class="chat-iframe"></iframe>`.
So it will be easier for an user to chat with the another person.
As it is locked, I have to do it manually by javascript.

So how can I create an `iframe` fetching the URL from `<a href="chat9867.php?user=Emma">...</a>"`?

Is there any way to do it using javascript/jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating an IFRAME using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726455/creating-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/Ls16u3ew/

```js
$('body').append('<iframe width="100%" class="chat-iframe" src="' + $('a').prop('href') + '"></iframe>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="chat9867.php?user=Emma">Chat With Emma</a>
```

I created the `iframe` on the fly (**dynamically**) & added `src` to it using `anchor` tag `href`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: When I used the `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` jQuery, then all Bootstrap Modals in my site stopped working! So I can't use it.

Comment: @user8427031 . Use some other `jQuery` version which suits your `bootstrap`. I used `jQuery` just for running the code, any version of `jQuery` will be fine for my code.

Comment: Can you provide me some other `jQuery`s?

Answer (score 0):

You can create iframe dynamically using plain JS or jQuery.

I will show for jQuery.

```
jQuery('<iframe>')
    .attr('src', jQuery('your_a_selector').attr('href'))
    .attr('width', '100%')
    .addClass('chat-iframe')
    .appendTo('#elementWhereAppendIt');
```

`#elementWhereAppendIt` is selector where new iframe will be placed to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `.attr()` for this..

```js
$('.iframe').attr('src',$('.chatLink').attr('href'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="chat9867.php?user=Emma" class="chatLink">Chat With Emma</a>
<iframe src="" class="iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: I already told, it is locked, so I can't edit it. And you've included a `class="chatLink"` inside the HTML. So, it is totally worthless!