# Post login information and submit form in html page loaded in another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to load an html page in another html page (multiple methods, javascript, jquery, html5) and I know how to post login information on an html page and submit, but here is the problem. When I load the original html page in another html page, I cannot access the form since it is in an object tag. Here is how I load the html page:

```
var URL = http://sampleurl.com/testpage
document.getElementById("testDIV").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="'+URL+'" width="100%" height="100%"></object>';
```

Now I am left with something like this:

```
<iframe class="container-frame" name="test" src="test" data-loaded="1">
    #document
    <html>
        <head>...</head>
        <body>
          ...
          <form>...</form>
          ...
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

I am unable to access the body inside the iframe using javascript to have information posted to a form in that body.

I have tried stuff like:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].childNodes...
```

But  I cannot get to the inner form element nor the body surrounding it. Is there a way that this can be done?

Comment: is the second page in same domain than first? If not you'll have a CORS error and not possible to access to the content on the iframe. Assuming you don't have this problem, you could do:
var iframe = document.getElementById(yourIframeID');
var content = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe

Comment: @charly3p The CORS issue is not present. It is taken care of by my nginx setup. 
This does not work. The problem is this: 
var iframe = document.getElementById("myID");
contains a <div> with <object> inside it and that object has the #document<html><head><body>. So iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document is returning the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Comment: Why are you using <object>? Why not just create the iframe and load the properties directly on the DOM?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726455/creating-an-iframe-using-javascript

Comment: @CarlosAlvesJorge It does matter what I use. Anything that I sue will end up with #document<html><head><body> inside it which makes it impossible to get to.

Comment: @MohammadEtemad if you can, put your code in a jsbin or jsfiddle and I'll check it